# UICollectionView chat bubble size

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, xcode9

I am currently working at a chat app in Xcode 9. I am not using stroyboards doing everything programmatically. For the "chat room" I am using a **UICollectionViewController** and I want the cells to adjust to the size of the text. I am calculating the size of the cells like that:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let size = CGSize(width: 250, height: 1000)
    let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
    let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: messages[indexPath.item].content as! String).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)], context: nil)

    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: estimatedFrame.height + 45)
}
```

So I am basically just calculating the size of the text and then return it as the cells hight. This works fine with short texts, but as soon as the text is longer than 6 lines, the last line is missing. From that point the calculated height is just wrong, because if I just set a constant height, the text shows. Can anyone spot a mistake or should I just use another method to get self sizing chat bubbles in a UICollectionView?

Comment: hi! did you find solution? i have the same problem...

Comment: @birdy No sorry, I ended up taking a completely different approach.